# How to set specific sidekiq queue to run one task at the time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I have a module which retrieves data from the instagram (with cookies, i.e. with logged in user), but instagram prevents to send a lot of requests at the time, so I'm looking for solution to perform one worker's task at the time (without parallel tasks of the same worker). From similar topics I did found a few solutions, like set concurrency to 1 or use gem https://github.com/brainopia/sidekiq-limit_fetch, but I don't want to reduce concurrency for all queues because of specific one, and also `sidekiq-limit_fetch` is not helps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to use Sidekiq for a usecase it is not designed for.  Consider using a different tool altogether.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#3-embrace-concurrency